# Swift Calendar - move to the next week

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I am making a calendar in swift starting from [this example](https://github.com/BadChoice/RVCalendarWeekView).

So far this is the result and I am showing only the 7 days staring from today.

[image]

I have added a button to show next week. So Far I have tried this:

```
func moveToNextWeek() {
    self.startDateInWeek = self.startDateInWeek?.dateByAddingDays(days: 7)

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({        
                    }, completion: { (completed) in
                            self.collectionView.reloadData()
                            self.weekFlowLayout?.invalidateLayout()

            })
    }
}
```

This just change the variable `startDateInWeek` which when the view loaded was declared as just `startDateInWeek = Date()`   (today's date).

However, when I pushed the button, another week is added but I have to scroll manually.

`dateByAddingDays()` is a `Date` extension declared as

```
func dateByAddingDays(days:Int)->Date{
    let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    var comp = DateComponents()
    comp.day = days
    return calendar.date(byAdding: comp, to: self)!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Calendar` provides a better way to calculate the beginning of next week even depending on the first weekday setting of the current locale:

```
let calendar = Locale.current.calendar
calendar.firstWeekday // Sunday == 1, Saturday == 7
let weekDayComponent = DateComponents(weekday:calendar.firstWeekday)
let startOfNextWeek = calendar.nextDate(after: Date(), matching: weekDayComponent, matchingPolicy: .nextTime)
```

Comment: thanks Vadian. This is a much better way. I don't think this is going to fix my problem though, isn't it?